# Swiper Nuxt3 - 500 ambiguous indirect export: Pagination

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, swiper.js

I would like to create a carousel in a nuxt3 application with swiper.
I have tried several ways but I always get the same error:

> 500 ambiguous indirect export: Pagination

Here is what I tried:

```
<swiper :options="swiperOptions">
            <swiper-slide v-for="(image, index) in product.images" :key="index">
              <img
                :src="image"
                :alt="product.title"
                class="h-full w-full object-contain object-center"
              />
            </swiper-slide>
            <div class="swiper-pagination" slot="pagination"></div>
          </swiper>
<script setup>
import SwiperCore, { Pagination } from "swiper/core";
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css";
​
SwiperCore.use([Pagination]);
​
  const products = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Product 1",
      price: 19.99,
      description: "Product 1 description",
      images: [
        "/images/product1_1.jpg",
        "/images/product1_2.jpg",
        "/images/product1_3.jpg",
      ],
      category: "Category A",
    },
    // Add more products as needed
  ];
};
​
// Swiper options
const swiperOptions = ref({
  pagination: { el: ".swiper-pagination", clickable: true },
});
</script>
```